# Oreo - Blinking the notification LED

Tags: java, android

in oreo how to enable notification led blink without notification sound,if i disable notification sound led does not blink

```
  Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 3000, 100)
          //  .setContentTitle("title")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cubs)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setSound(null)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification);
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oreo, the mechanism of NotificationChannel was introduced. You must set the channel and enable lights like this,

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = "Notification";
    String description = "Notification";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("someChannelID", name, importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.setShowBadge(true);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.setSound(uri);
    if (notificationManager != null)  notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context, "someChannelID")
            .setContentTitle(contentTitleText)
            .setContentText(contentContentText)
            .setNumber(1)
            .setSmallIcon(whiteLogo)
            .setBadgeIconType(whiteLogo)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification);
    }
}

else {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(whiteLogo)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitleText)
            .setContentText(contentContentText)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setNumber(1)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(colorPPDOrange, 1000, 2000);
            .setSound(uri);
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html for more help on Notifications.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the crash?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code
      `import android.app.Notification;
       import android.app.NotificationChannel;
       import android.app.NotificationManager;
       import android.app.PendingIntent;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.media.RingtoneManager;
       import android.net.Uri;
       import android.os.Build;
       import          android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.util.Log;

```
   public abstract class MainActivity extends      Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle        savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NotificationManager notificationManager    =
            (NotificationManager)   getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String channelId = "test-channel";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=    Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel newIncidentChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Test Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(newIncidentChannel);
     }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Test")
                    .setContentText("Text")
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()%10000);
    notificationManager.notify("test", NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}
`